# How to ensure security in Ubuntu 20 for those not interested in it?

Tags: security

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for a couple of years as a new user and am tired of having constant apparent security issues (like tor browser offering to save a file in a directory where I never saved anything from tor).

I do not have open ports (out of 65536) by *nmap*, have firewall enabled,
install all supported updates daily, try not to install unsupported software (except for Iris similar to redshift),use tor even for email. I tried *openvpn* with free vpns, but after a couple of weeks openvpn stopped working.
In a previous installation I used *tiger* (installed from Ubuntu repositories), but it provides only reports with potential security issues and doesn't fix them.
I also access the internet from a Windows virtual machine for work.

I heard about some graph-based ultimate security auditing tool like grapl (https://www.graplsecurity.com/), but the tutorial seems to be mostly for Windows security auditing. Maybe you could explain how to use grapl in Ubuntu?

How can I ensure the effective security in Ubuntu (for business and research) after fresh install so that to spend minimum time on it? How can the potential unauthorized breaches resulting from reading this post be prevented?

Comment: What exactly are you concerned about? Are you worried about getting a virus from browsing the internet, or someone directly attacking your computer? I don't understand what you mean by your tor comment. How is saving a file in a different place a security hole by itself?

Comment: I also find it worth noting that free VPNs have the possibility of being a security risk themselves, so it's best only to use the ones you have reason to trust.

Comment: Regarding tor, I saved several files in a Desktop directory which I selected manually (by navigating from hidden folders into regular Desktop), and for saving another file tor suggested a nested subfolder "Python networking" in another desktop folder where I never navigated from tor. I don't know how this can be a security issue, but it was not authorized as I never showed tor the path to this folder.

Comment: I am concerned about someone directly attacking my computer, especially those who are more familiar with open-source and programming not dead by coronavirus yet.

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates that you are concerned about being directly targeted, so that's rather a surprise. Defense against somebody targeting you can be quite different from general precautions against random browser drive-bys and cryptominers and phishing. Also, your title specifies "not interested in [security]," but you clearly are very interested in security. Which target audience should answers write for?

Comment: To clarify, when I said "directly attacking", I meant sitting at a console and saying "I'm gonna attack this computer" as opposed to people creating malicious websites or embedded content, which has a wider range of targets.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not have open ports (out of 65536) by nmap, have firewall enabled, install all supported updates daily, try not to install unsupported software (except for Iris similar to redshift),use tor even for email.

All you do here is not going to improve security. Ports are only open when software from your system needs an open port to function. Generally that happens when you use server software.

Out of the box Ubuntu already has this done such you do not need to worry about it.

You are afraid of someone from the outside breaching the system when Linux in general is set up to be a multi-user system?  A multi user system already needs to be  secure on the INSIDE. Let alone from the OUTSIDE. Linux is secure by design.

If there was something that would make it easy to break in a random Linux based computer the internet would explode. The person that manages that would be instantly famous. Has not happened and is unlikely to happen.

> I am concerned about someone directly attacking my computer"

Why? Attacks happen all the time (where I work we get hit on our google cloud engines about 1 million times a day from mostly Chinese bots). I would worry about people getting actual access ;-) But in regards to us desktop users: Linux is more secure than (for instance) Windows (by design). We (as of today) are 100% virus free. The reason is that Linux is used by people that love to tinker with it.

The main issues we had over the last 10 years: the NSA maintaining security related packages where someone got away with keeping a backdoor in it. Yes a serious issue. But that kind of problems are rare and to be honest... impossible for us to prevent. No amount of effort from a user would have prevented it.
Same with an issue Mint had: someone stupidly made it easy for a hacker to alter the installation software. Ubuntu had an installer where the password used during install remained plain text on the installed system.

Never ever did we have a system breached where it was not the user itself that made a mistake: using 12345 as a password is bad. Using 12345 as a password for phpadmin is asking for it.

At some point you and I need to trust someone. Canonical has a good track record so my faith is with them. It is far better than the track record of Microsoft or Apple.

Generic suggestions:

1. use a good password
2. do not install software you do not intend to use
3. do not install software from untrusted sources
4. keep your system updated. Use an LTS. Or keep upgrading to the latest version
5. do not execute command that you do not understand

and NOBODY is going to breach your system.

If that is not enough:

6. don't put personal files on your system and keep them on an USB that you do not mount when you do not need it mounted.
7. Use encryption on all disks if you want or use encryption on specific directories or files.

Thing not to do...

Do not install a virus scanner. Those are useless on Linux since those use Windows based rules on a different OS. As of today (you never know if we do in  the future) we do not have viruses; viruses are possible on Linux but it would require you yourself to install it. And that is a breach of #2.
All you do is burn resources you could use for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this question would best be addressed in separate parts, so here we go:

> like tor browser offering to save a file in a directory where I never saved anything from tor)

Tor suggesting another folder to save a file is not a security hole, even if you have not been to it before (which I would assume you had been by accident, otherwise it's likely a bug that it was suggested). A program does not need to be granted access to ask you where to save something, or even to read files in your home folder, including your Desktop. This is true of most operating systems. MacOS Catalina is a notable exception, but even on that programs can still ask for a file location in your Desktop. Having the location of a file does not mean you have the ability to read it.

Simply because Tor can access your Desktop does not mean that any website can. A website can only access a file if IT had the user select one, which is different from when Tor asks for a download location.

> I am concerned about someone directly attacking my computer

The risk of your computer being attacked directly is very small as it would be behind your router, or one at your business. Some VPNs can actually increase risk here by allowing other users of the same VPN to reach your device.

> How can the potential unauthorized breaches resulting from reading this post be prevented?

There is virtually no risk in reading this post, especially if you have no browser plugins or extensions like Adobe Flash, as long as you don't go to a website and give it your credit card info or select a file to be accessed.

> How can I ensure the effective security in Ubuntu (for business and research) after fresh install so that to spend minimum time on it?

This is pretty much done from a fresh install, as one of Ubuntu's goals is to be [Secure by default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_by_default).

> Maybe you could explain how to use grapl in Ubuntu?

I believe `grapl` is more targeted at websites and more large-scale deployments then it is desktop environments, and wouldn't recommend it for your apparent use case. I have heard good things about [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/), although I have barely ever touched it myself.

If you have other minor questions, you can comment on this post. If you have more major questions, either edit your post or consider [InfoSec](https://security.stackexchange.com/).